# Tweepy error with install involving parse requirements

Tags: python, installation, tweepy

I have been trying to install `tweepy` on a Windows, and it returns an error. Specifically it says:

> TypeError: parse_requirements <> got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'

My install code was:

> pip install tweepy

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Am not sure if you solved the issue. 
Try upgrading `pip` to `pip6.0+`, this resolved the same issue i had on my Ubuntu Machine. You can give it a try

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: I had version 1.4.1, definitely time for an upgrade.