# Tweepy Installation Issue

Tags: python, tweepy

I am having problems with importing tweedy:

```
this is the error received

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "star_twitter.py", line 71, in <module>
send_to_twitter(get_price())
File "star_twitter.py", line 9, in send_to_twitter
import tweepy
ImportError: No module named tweepy
```

I tried re-installing it but now am receiving the following error message

```
Downloading/unpacking tweepy
Downloading tweepy-3.3.0.tar.gz
Running setup.py egg_info for package tweepy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
File "/home/pi/build/tweepy/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=uuid.uuid1())
TypeError: parse_requirements() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

File "/home/pi/build/tweepy/setup.py", line 17, in <module>

install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=uuid.uuid1())

TypeError: parse_requirements() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in    /home/pi/build/tweepy
 Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Your assistance will be appreciated

Comment: Which version of python and pip are you using?

Comment: Are you on Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: pyhon 3.2.3 I am running it on a raspberry pi ssh'ed  from my mac

Comment: So I guess you're running a Linux on your Pi. Can you let us know your `pip` version?

Comment: pip version is pip 1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: running Raspbian on the raspberry pi

Comment: How is it that you're saying it's python 3.2 but pip saying it's 2.7?

Comment: i am using python3 to run .py scripts ...

Comment: on the raspberry i have python and 2.7.3 and installed python 3.2.3 .. the pip version .. i think i may have installed python 3 on a virtualenv, not sure if this helps

Answer (score 1):

You may have faced [known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079152/tweepy-error-with-install-involving-parse-requirements). Try upgrading pip.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score -1):

The fact that you're using virtualenv does help. If you used `sudo` trying to install tweepy then that's  where the installation went wrong.

Try using `pip install tweepy` only.

If you're still getting an error from that then your virtualenv has probably became corrup. Do the following:

```
$ deactivate
$ rmvirtualenv nlmanagement
$ mkvirtualenv nlmanagement
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Try the `pip` installation first and only use that for future needs in virtualenv.

Comment: wasn't able to run the above command got the following error message : bash: rmvirtualenv: command not found