# Install Tweepy on Ubuntu Shared Server

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, tweepy

Any ideas on how I can successfully install tweepy?

Looks like I am missing some dependencies but not really sure what this error means exactly:

```
    $ pip install tweepy
Downloading/unpacking tweepy
  Downloading tweepy-3.5.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package tweepy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/home/user/build/tweepy/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=uuid.uuid1())
    TypeError: parse_requirements() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/home/user/build/tweepy/setup.py", line 17, in <module>

    install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=uuid.uuid1())

TypeError: parse_requirements() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an outdated version of PiP. Will ask the host to upgrade.
[Tweepy error with install involving parse requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079152/tweepy-error-with-install-involving-parse-requirements)